# C - ignoring whitespace with sscanf

Tags: c, parsing, strtok, scanf

I've been trying to figure this out, and I sort of have a work around but I just wanted to check that I'm not missing something obvious. Basically, I have a series of commands that follow certain rules. Anything containing a digit, ASCII letter, or certain symbols is a token and <,>,|,&&,;,etc are delimiters. I need to be able to tell which one I just found and store them in an array.

So in a while loop I have

```
a = sscanf (cp, "%[0-9a-zA-Z!@:/-.,^+% ]", str);
```

I've included a space as one of the symbols to look for since I couldn't figure out any other way. Instead, after I get the word (plus nay possible spaces) I call

```
 delimiters[] = " ";
 token = strtok(str, delimiters);
```

Which should remove the whitespace, leaving me with just a token (and if there was no space, it just doesn't change the word). I'm just curious if there's a way to do something similar with sscanf, since I know that it already breaks up strings if there's a whitespace between them, but if you call it again and it sees the whitespace, it just doesn't read anything.

If not, that's fine too. It's just been bugging my all day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ignoring whitespace with sscanf in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292826/ignoring-whitespace-with-sscanf-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your format to

```
a = sscanf (cp, " %[0-9a-zA-Z!@:/-.,^+%]", str);
```

The leading `' '` in the format skips a [possibly empty] sequence of white space characters, and then you'd scan in a sequence of non-space admissible token characters.

Comment: But doesn't that mean there has to be a whitespace before my string? So even if there happened to be no whitespace between the tokens and delimiters, would that still work? (sorry I'd check myself but I'm on my cell phone at the moment)

Comment: @user1777900 it means skip any whitespace before your string if any is present.

Comment: @user1777900 The sequence of white space that a space in the format string consumes may be empty. If there is no whitespace, the psace matches an empty sequence of white space tokens.